# I can't import a file.txt in py3

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I'm trying to write a program on py3. I have saved 2 raw texts in the same directory as "programm.py" but the program can't find the texts.
I'm using emacs, and I wrote:

```py
from __future__ import division
import nltk, sys, matplotlib, numpy, re, pprint, codecs
from os import path
text1 = "/home/giovanni/Scrivania/Giovanni/programmi/Esame/Milton.txt"
text2 = "/home/giovanni/Scrivania/Giovanni/programmi/Esame/Sksp.txt"
from nltk import ngrams
s_tokenizer = nltk.data.load("tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle")
w_tokenizer = nltk.word_tokenize("text")
print(text1)
```

but when I run it in py3 it doesn't print text1 (I used it to see if it works)

```
>>> import programma1
>>>
```

Instead, if I ask to print in py3 it can't find the file

```
>>> import programma1
>>> text1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'text1' is not defined
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few independent issues going on here. As @Yash Kanojia correctly pointed out, to get the contents of the files you need to read them, rather than just have their address.

The reason you can't access `text1` is that it isn't a global variable. To access it, you need to use `programma1.text1`.

I've also moved all the import statements to the top of `programma1.py` as it's seen as good practice :)

Full code:

`programma1.py`:

```
from __future__ import division
import nltk, sys, matplotlib, numpy, re, pprint, codecs
from nltk import ngrams
from os import path

with open("/home/giovanni/Scrivania/Giovanni/programmi/Esame/Milton.txt") as file1:
    text1 = file1.read()

with open("/home/giovanni/Scrivania/Giovanni/programmi/Esame/Sksp.txt") as file2:
    text2 = file2.read()

s_tokenizer = nltk.data.load("tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle")
w_tokenizer = nltk.word_tokenize("text")

#print(text1)
```

`main.py`:

```
import programma1

print(programma1.text1)
```

**EDIT:**

I presume you wanted to load the contents of the files into the tokenizer. If you do, replace this line:

```
w_tokenizer = nltk.word_tokenize("text")
```

with this line

```
w_tokenizer = nltk.word_tokenize(text1 + "\n" + text2)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't matter because Python has garbage collection.

Comment: You will notice that if you run open a file in write mode without assigning it to a variable, you will be able to write to that file in other programs. If you assign it to a variable, you can't, because Python's garbage collection won't destroy it.

Comment: now when i run in py print(programma1.text1) it sais => AttributeError: module 'programma1' has no attribute 'text1'

Comment: Have you copied both pieces of code completely, because it works on my computer...

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('/home/giovanni/Scrivania/Giovanni/programmi/Esame/Milton.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
print(data)
```

Comment: add context so we can learn from it. (prevents downvoting and winning low-qaulity post review award 2019).